# Storing API keys in salesforce to callout to custom service

Tags: apex, api, callout, encryption

We have our own app in Salesforce.When a customer service agent (non-privileged user) initiates/completes a task, we need to let our other systems know (via message bus) to do other things.

Now, the easy part is storing the key in a secure encrypted config field. The confusing part is having these customer agent's workflows be able to use the field and post out to our external service. The obvious solution is to enable the agent's profile to read encrypted data, but I feel like that defeats the purpose of obscuring/hiding API keys from everyone else, other than admin devops like myself.

How have other people worked around this?

Comment: You could possibly use named credentials to store them securely. I know it supports basic and oauth but I'm not sure if it would work for storing API keys: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=0

Comment: Oh snap - i got the badge hammer.... @kosh - Let me know if the duplicate does not answer your question and I will undupe it. I do believe it is a dupe though and been asked and answered before